# How do I get a floppy drive working?

Tags: 10.04, floppy

A friend's mum has some childhood photos on a "thing" she wanted me to access.  Turns out to be an old floppy drive.  I dusted off my old UltrayBay floppy drive for the T21 laptop I still have kicking around.

I had to reboot to get floppy drive to show on desktop.  But it reads all disks as blank, regardless of content.  So I cannot say for sure if these photos can be accessed or not.

I know it's ancient tech, but quite important to get working in this instance...

I have tried loading floppy module:

```
sudo modprobe floppy
```

But no dice.

Comment: Do you know that the floppy drive works? Do you know that the floppy disk works? Either, or both, could have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Lee Filter](http://fleamour.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/how-to-get-internal-floppy-drive-recognized-under-xubuntu-10-04-lts/)

Answer (score 1):

Via the menu option System --> Administration --> Users and Groups

Click on Advanced Settings (bottom right - under your account that is shown - there may be more than one user shown)

Click on User Privileges and check the box that says "Use floppy Drives"

[image]

Insert your floppy disk into your disk drive and then type in a terminal:

```
udisks --mount /dev/fd
```

Look on your desktop and the floppy icon should be there ready for you to access.

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+question/120571)

Comment: Installed Linux Floppy Utilities & followed these guides:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9527243&postcount=37

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10683138&postcount=4

Comment: ok - the second link is saying the same as me.

Comment: except: "2. Use the old version of udisks"